# Finding all combinations of capture groups with regex

Tags: java, regex

How to get all combinations of Capture-Groups from a regex?

Given the string `Max Michael van Mustermann` I want to generate the pairs `(Max)(Michael van Mustermann)`, `(Max Michael)(van Mustermann)` and `(Max Michael van)(Mustermann)`.
This *should* be doable by the pattern `^(.+) (.+)$` (where space is the separating char). However this does not work as intended as the first capture-group greedily captures `Max Michael van`, leaves `Mustermann` to the second capture-group and terminates the evaluation because the whole string has been matched.

I tried using solutions for overlapping matches (`(?=<regex>)`), but this didn't yield the desired results (eating away one character after the other from the front, but still greedy as before).

I tried making the first capture-group lazy, but that just reverses the problem. No combination of laziness and/or greediness will yield the match `(Max Michael)(van Mustermann)`.

As far as I understand regex, it tries to fit the whole string in the first `.+`, can't match the second `.+` and continues to release characters from the first `.+` to be matched by the second `.+` until a match occurs (in my case around the last space). **I want the regex-engine to continue to release characters until no characters are left in the first `.+`.**

---

My actual problem:
I have a list of names as strings. I do not know where to separate them in first-name and last-name. However, I have another list of the same names, but with first-name and last-name reversed.

My idea is to find all combinations of capture-groups in the first list, reverse their order and match them against the second list.

```
# First list
Max van Mustermann
Miriam Musterfrau
Alice Bobina Charlston

# Second list
van Mustermann Max       (van is part of last-name)
Musterfrau Miriam
Charlston Alice Bobina   (Bobina is part of first-name)
```

Some roughly desired code:

```
String first = "Max van Mustermann";
String second = "van Mustermann Max";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.+) (.+)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(first);
while (matcher.find()) { // This is obviously not correct, it will only find the first match
    String swapped = matcher.group(2) + " " + matcher.group(1);
    if(second.equals(swapped)){
        // Success!
    }
}
```

*This can be solved without regex. It was just the hook that made me investigate the problem.*

Comment: Wouldn't this be much simpler using basic string operations?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think it's possible to do with a single regular expression search. However, you can do it with one search and one comparison:

```
String first = "Max van Mustermann";
String second = "van Mustermann Max";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*)" + Pattern.quote(second) + "(.*)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(first + " " + first);
if (matcher.matches()) {
  if ((" " + second + " ").equals(matcher.group(2) + " " + matcher.group(1))) {
    // Success!
  }
}
```

Explanation: 
we make a string which is a "doubled" first string:

*Max van Mustermann Max van Mustermann*

If the second string is just a rotated copy of the first string, then it should match this doubled first string:

*Max **van Mustermann Max** van Mustermann*

Then we need to check that what is rest on the doubled string is equal to the second string. We just need to take the ending " van Mustermann" and append it with the beginning "Max ". The result must be equal to the second string appended with spaces on both sides:

```
" van Mustermann" + " " + "Max " => " van Mustermann Max "
```

Comment: Updated the answer, the previous version with trim() could give false positives, e.g. for `first = "Maxvan Mustermann"`

Answer (score 0):

I have found a regex which does almost exactly what you want:

```
String first = "Alice Bobina Charlston Max van Mustermann Miriam Musterfrau";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=^(.*)\\G)( ?\\w+)(?= (.*$))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(first);
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.printf("(%s)(%s)%n", matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3));
}
```

Output:

```
(Alice)(Bobina Charlston Max van Mustermann Miriam Musterfrau)
(Alice Bobina)(Charlston Max van Mustermann Miriam Musterfrau)
(Alice Bobina Charlston)(Max van Mustermann Miriam Musterfrau)
(Alice Bobina Charlston Max)(van Mustermann Miriam Musterfrau)
(Alice Bobina Charlston Max van)(Mustermann Miriam Musterfrau)
(Alice Bobina Charlston Max van Mustermann)(Miriam Musterfrau)
(Alice Bobina Charlston Max van Mustermann Miriam)(Musterfrau)
```

The only difference is that it splits the text into 3 groups, not 2, and you must manually combine the first two groups to get the result. With this pattern your code will look like:

```
String first = "Max van Mustermann";
String second = "van Mustermann Max";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=^(.*)\\G)( ?\\w+)(?= (.*$))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(first);
while (matcher.find()) { 
  String swapped = matcher.group(3) + " " + matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2);
  if(second.equals(swapped)) {
    // Success!
  }
}
```

The magic is done by anchoring the pattern to the position of the last match by using  `\G`.

This solution is not as effective as my previous solution, but just proves that what you ask is achievable with a regular expression.